# JQuery addClass without it having effect on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this class `fade` that I need my elements to have for external plugins and
I have this code where I want an element to fadeIn and Out using JQuery and for that I have to remove de class `fade` and when I add it again after my fadeIn it fades again.

How can I add a class and prevent it from taking action?

```
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL+page,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "html",
    data: {},
    success: function (data, status) {
        if(action == true){
            target.removeClass('fade').fadeOut(500, function(){
                target.html(data).fadeIn(500).addClass('fade'); <-----------
            });
        }
    }
});
```

It's from bootstrap:

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
          transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}
```

Comment: Where is action declared? Don't you mean status? :)

Comment: I mean 'taking action' like be affected by the `class` in `css`

Comment: You can't. If you don't want a class to have an effect, don't specify those effects in the CSS for that particular class. Though you could specifically undo the changes that the CSS implements, but that's very fragile.

Comment: `target, action` post something about these. what is the use of adding class `fade` to the target.

Comment: do you have to remove the class at all? what I mean is: how is it conflicting with the jQuery fade?

Comment: Is the class 'fade' just an identifier for the plugin or does the class have CSS code? If there is CSS associated with it, can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your requirements, but if you want to have the class `fade` applied to the element, but you don't want it to have the stylesheet's properties applied to it, you can make use of another class to indicate that the element should not have the effect, and use the pseudo selector `not` on the stylesheet.

Like this:

```
// Just add another class with the fade one. "no-effect" for example.
target.html(data).fadeIn(500).addClass('fade no-effect');
```

And use the pseudo `not` on the css:

```
.fade:not(.no-effect) {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}
```

This way the transition will only be applied to elements that have the `.fade` class, but don't have the `.no-effect` class.

Hope it helps someway.

Comment: Very very nice solution. Thank you. I have to get around CSS3 definitely